# Why Exception is a class, not a struct?

Tags: c#, class, exception, struct

- Exception represents a single piece of information.
- Exceptions are (or should be) by definition rare occurrence in application lifetime so boxing, unboxing and copying are not an issue I think.
- Exceptions almost always go out of scope from where they were created, so there is a risk of having reference to exception stored somewhere making it good candidate for promotion to next GC generation, while structs are easier to cleanup.
- Immutable Struct is thread safe.
- You never want Exception to be null (even compiler or CLR forces this, try doing whats below):

  ```
  throw null;
  ```

  then, you'll get:

  ```
  NullReferenceException
  ```

**Is there any specific reason for why Exceptions are classes?**

Comment: ''You never want Exception to be null'' Exception.InnerException can be checked for null. And structures requires to be allocated in stack, but what will you allocate in case of stack overflow? Also ''Structs can implement an interface but they cannot inherit from another struct'' as doc said

Comment: Many answers, but a very important one is that you can't have a hierarchy of structs - and a hierarchy of Exceptions is very important and is fundamental to the way that `catch` works (i.e. you `catch` Exceptions from most- to least- derived to handle specific cases before general cases).

Comment: @oleksa You're totally right. Inheritance is big argument for having Exceptions as classes.

Comment: Also an inner exception would be impossible, which would forbid to throw an higher level exception with the context of the original one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two most important things:

- Structures cannot be inherited, so you can't make any hierarchy in your exceptions
- In case of StackOverflowException you can't allocate memory on stack, you need a heap

Comment: [*In case of StackOverflowException you can't allocate memory on stack, you need a heap*]
I don't think that's the reason. We also have `OutOfMemoryException`.